# Appending all incoming path parameters to the proxy_pass URL

Tags: nginx, http, proxypass

I want to create a mapping such that, if a request comes in with a path `some-path` gets appended to the `proxy_pass` URL. For example as shown below:

```
location /hi/[some-path] {
    proxy_pass https://mywebsite.com/[some-path]
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Is that possible?

```
Incoming Request:
   https://foo.bar/hi/some-path/1/2/3

Proxy Passed To:
   https://mywebsite.com/some-path/1/2/3
```

Comment: You don't need the `[some-path]` bit. Anything after the `/hi/` is automatically added after the `/` in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith Should my `proxy_pass` statement then just be `proxy_pass https://mywebsite.com/`?

Comment: Yes, `location /hi/ { proxy_pass https://mywebsite.com/; }` will perform the transformation in your question.